# TYPO3 Flux field text - csv data

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using fluidcontent and inside a flux text field I'm saving csv data.
How can I split the string on every newline? It looks like the \n is not being saved.

The following code does not work.

```
<v:iterator.explode content="{settings.csv}" glue="\n" as="lines">
```

The split between columns works well with

```
<v:iterator.explode content="{settings.csv}" glue=";" as="elements">
```

I'm thankful for every help.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [CommaSeparatedValueProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/#dataprocessing) in the FLUIDTEMPLATE object to generate an array with all the lines and fields.

Answer (score 0):

To split on newline the glue argument needs a value of "constant:LF" as described in the [documentation](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Iterator/ExplodeViewHelper.html#arguments)

```
<v:iterator.explode content="{settings.csv}" glue="constant:LF" as="line">
  {line}
</v:iterator.explode>
```